# new line in standalone

Tags: line-breaking, standalone

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

line1

line2

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the output everything is on one line:

[image]

How to have a new line in `standalone`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `varwidth` option will allow line breaks:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

line1

line2

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- (2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]